# How to join through an intermediary table transparently

Tags: mysql, left-join

### Simple version

Let's say I have two tables:

**Contacts**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Sally |
| 3 | Jane |

**Activities**

| id | contact_id | type | subject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Meeting | Strategy planning |
| 2 | 1 | Phone Call | Follow-up on lead |
| 3 | 1 | Phone Call | Second follow-up |
| 4 | 3 | Meeting | Strategy planning 2 |

I can do a simple `LEFT JOIN` to retrieve contacts who may have an activity of a certain type:

```sql
SELECT name, subject
FROM Contacts c
LEFT JOIN Activities a ON a.contact_id = c.id AND a.type = 'Meeting'
```

This will give me all my contacts, with their meetings if they have any:

| name | subject |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | *null* |
| Sally | *null* |
| Jane | Strategy planning |
| Jane | Strategy planning 2 |

Notice that I get 2 rows for Jane because she has 2 meetings. I *do not* get 2 rows for Bob, even though he has 2 activities, because they are excluded by the ON clause. I also get a row for Sally, even though she doesn't have any activities of any kind.

### With extra join table

Ok, that's what I want to be able to do, but the monkey-wrench is that my schema doesn't look like that. It has an intermediary table (because more than one contact could be part of an activity). The real schema looks like the above but with no `contact_id` column for Activities:

**Contacts**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Sally |
| 3 | Jane |

**Activities**

| id | type | subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Meeting | Strategy planning |
| 2 | Phone Call | Follow-up on lead |
| 3 | Phone Call | Second follow-up |
| 4 | Meeting | Strategy planning 2 |

**Activity_Contact**

| activity_id | contact_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |

And this is where I'm stuck. How do I perform the same type of `LEFT JOIN` from Contacts to Activities? If I add two joins to the query, then I end up with duplicate rows for Bob (because he has 2 entries in the Activity_Contact table, even though the 2nd join excludes his activities):

```sql
SELECT name, subject
FROM Contacts c
LEFT JOIN Activity_Contact ac ON ac.contact_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN Activities a ON a.id = ac.activity_id AND a.type = 'Meeting'
```

| name | subject |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | *null* |
| Bob | *null* |
| Sally | *null* |
| Jane | Strategy planning |
| Jane | Strategy planning 2 |

I could use `GROUP BY` to get only one Bob, but that would squash the rows for Jane as well.

What I really want is to transparently join through the intermediary table as if it wasn't even there. Is there a way to do that in MySql?

Comment: @Strawberry ok I've read through that and I believe I provided everything in this question that was asked for. Am I missing something?

Comment: I too believe I've provided everything, which places us at an impasse :-(

Comment: My intent was to prompt you to provide the missing information; it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Would just making your current select `DISTINCT` give you the behavior your want:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.name, c.subject
FROM Contacts c
LEFT JOIN Activity_Contact ac ON ac.contact_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN Activities a ON a.id = ac.activity_id AND a.type = 'Meeting';
```

Note: You could get the same result as above by grouping by *both* `name` and `subject`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This question is a distilled & very oversimplified piece of a much larger puzzle. What I'm actually writing is a search-builder-gui that can compose very complex queries. I was really hoping to encapsulate the behavior of `LEFT JOIN` across intermediary tables so the user gets the same experience as when it's a 1-1 join. If there's no way to do what I want in SQL, then I'll have to go back to the drawing board, but I thought it was worth asking.

Comment: @Coleman If I "get" your question, the answer is yes, there are ways to generally do what you want.  For instance, you could use analytic functions (e.g. `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK`) to label the records you want across multiple joins.  In that case, things like duplication of records, as you have in your current question, can be dealt with.

Comment: @Coleman If `DISTINCT` is not an option in your case, you could `JOIN` your pivot and activities tables in a subquery, and then `LEFT JOIN` it to contacts

Comment: @Pepper if you turn that into an answer I'll upvote it because that sounds like what I want.

Comment: @Coleman But keep in mind that sometimes joining to an intermediate subquery can hurt performance.  In certain cases, your current query would be optimal.

Comment: Eh? Out of coffee again. TB?